# Mask a numpy array for each row until a certain column

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to mask certain columns for each row of a matrix

```
a = np.tril(np.random.rand(5))

array([[0.06954394, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.06954394, 0.09570674, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.06954394, 0.09570674, 0.37445553, 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.06954394, 0.09570674, 0.37445553, 0.97418849, 0.        ],
       [0.06954394, 0.09570674, 0.37445553, 0.97418849, 0.76897831]])
```

from row 3 onwards I want to mask the certain columns to np.nan

ie I want

a[3,1], a[4,0] and a[4,1] to be nans

I tried

```
a[[3,4],[[0],[0,1]]] = np.nan
```

but I get this error

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-200-356c1356a616> in <module>
----> 1 a[[3,4],[[0],[0,1]]]=np.nan

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Is there also a more general way to do this.

If I have array of rows and list of array of columns of each row to be naned

```
a[[row_array],[[col_array for row_1],[col_array for row_2],...]] = np.nan
```

Comment: Show the actual output you expect. The correct index is `[3, 4, 4], [0, 0, 1]` BTW

Comment: 'a[[row_array],[[col_array for row_1],[col_array for row_2],...]] = np.nan' is not how np indexing works. In your case, the arguments of '__ getitem__' need to be two flat lists where each position 'i' in the first list contains the row index and position 'i' in the second flat list contains the column index. Basically, you just have to flatten your second list of lists and duplicate the values in the first row list accordingly